# dpdk19.11 i40e NIC cant send tcp packages split by rte_gso_segment

Tags: dpdk

I am using GSO(generic segment offload) feature in dpdk 19.11, I do the following  GSO related initialization by referring to testpmd:

```
struct rte_gso_ctx gso_ctx;
static int gso_ctx_setup(struct rte_gso_ctx *gso_ctx, int port_id)
{
    uint32_t gso_types;
    char pool_name[64];

    struct rte_mempool *mp;      /* Mempool for GSO packets */

    /* initialize GSO context */
    gso_types = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO;
    snprintf(pool_name, sizeof(pool_name), "gso_%d", port_id);
    mp = rte_mempool_lookup((const char *)pool_name);
    if (!mp) {
        mp = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create(pool_name, 128 * 10,
            4, 0,
            RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM + 128,
            SOCKET_ID_ANY);
        if (!mp) {
            printf("failed to create mbuf pool for device %d\n",port_id);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    gso_ctx->direct_pool = mp;
    gso_ctx->indirect_pool = mp;
    gso_ctx->gso_types = gso_types;
    gso_ctx->gso_size = 1514;
    gso_ctx->flag = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

then I use the following function to split and send the input large tcp packets:

```
#define GSO_MAX_PKT_BURST 128
uint32_t tx_xmit(struct rte_mbuf *pkt)
{
    uint32_t sent_pkts = 0;
    struct rte_mbuf *gso_segments[GSO_MAX_PKT_BURST];
    uint16_t nb_segments = 0;
    int ret;

    ret = rte_gso_segment(pkt, &gso_ctx, &gso_segments[nb_segments], GSO_MAX_PKT_BURST - nb_segments);
    if (ret > 0) {
        nb_segments += ret;
    } else {
        printf("unable to segment packet\n");
        rte_pktmbuf_free(pkts[0]);
    }

    rte_eth_tx_burst(port_id, queue_id, &gso_segments[0], nb_segments);
}
```

The mbuf passed to tx_xmit looks like this:

```
struct rte_mbuf *head = m;
for (int i = 0; i < head->nb_segs; i++) {
    m->ol_flags = PKT_TX_IPV4 | PKT_TX_TCP_CKSUM | PKT_TX_IP_CKSUM | PKT_TX_TCP_SEG | DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO;
    // I'm sure the TCP header and data are correct.
    m->data_len = 1514;
    m->pkt_len = 1514 + 1460 + 1460 ....;
    m->l2_len = 14;
    m->l3_len = 20;
    m->l4_len = 20;
    m = m->next;
}
```

The preceding data is split by the rte_gso_segment function and transferred to the rte_eth_tx_burst function, and then transferred to the i40e_xmit_pkts function. However, the data cannot be sent out.

mbuf is as follows:

```
Thread 4 "tcpip_thread_00" hit Breakpoint 1, i40e_xmit_pkts (tx_queue=0x1fff359c0,
    tx_pkts=0x7ffff5d1adc0, nb_pkts=3)
    at /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/dpdk-19.11/drivers/net/i40e/i40e_rxtx.c:994
994     {
(gdb) p *tx_pkts[0]
$1 = {cacheline0 = 0x1da918f00, buf_addr = 0x1da918f80, {buf_iova = 13330648960,
    buf_physaddr = 13330648960}, rearm_data = 0x1da918f10, data_off = 128, {
    refcnt_atomic = {cnt = 1}, refcnt = 1}, nb_segs = 2, port = 65535,
  ol_flags = 58546795155816448, rx_descriptor_fields1 = 0x1da918f20, {packet_type = 0, {
      l2_type = 0, l3_type = 0, l4_type = 0, tun_type = 0, {
        inner_esp_next_proto = 0 '\000', {inner_l2_type = 0 '\000',
          inner_l3_type = 0 '\000'}}, inner_l4_type = 0}}, pkt_len = 1514,
  data_len = 54, vlan_tci = 0, {hash = {rss = 0, fdir = {{{hash = 0, id = 0}, lo = 0},
        hi = 0}, sched = {queue_id = 0, traffic_class = 0 '\000', color = 0 '\000',
        reserved = 0}, txadapter = {reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 0, txq = 0}, usr = 0}},
  vlan_tci_outer = 0, buf_len = 256, timestamp = 0, cacheline1 = 0x1da918f40, {
    userdata = 0x0, udata64 = 0}, pool = 0x1da9a8c00, next = 0x1da918d40, {
    tx_offload = 1313294, {l2_len = 14, l3_len = 20, l4_len = 20, tso_segsz = 0,
      outer_l3_len = 0, outer_l2_len = 0}}, priv_size = 0, timesync = 0, seqn = 0,
  shinfo = 0x0, dynfield1 = {0, 0}}
(gdb) p *tx_pkts[0]->next
$2 = {cacheline0 = 0x1da918d40, buf_addr = 0x1e0d33ac8, {buf_iova = 13435615944,
    buf_physaddr = 13435615944}, rearm_data = 0x1da918d50, data_off = 182, {
    refcnt_atomic = {cnt = 1}, refcnt = 1}, nb_segs = 1, port = 65535,
  ol_flags = 4670232813583204352, rx_descriptor_fields1 = 0x1da918d60, {
    packet_type = 0, {l2_type = 0, l3_type = 0, l4_type = 0, tun_type = 0, {
        inner_esp_next_proto = 0 '\000', {inner_l2_type = 0 '\000',
          inner_l3_type = 0 '\000'}}, inner_l4_type = 0}}, pkt_len = 1514,
  data_len = 1460, vlan_tci = 0, {hash = {rss = 0, fdir = {{{hash = 0, id = 0},
          lo = 0}, hi = 0}, sched = {queue_id = 0, traffic_class = 0 '\000',
        color = 0 '\000', reserved = 0}, txadapter = {reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 0,
        txq = 0}, usr = 0}}, vlan_tci_outer = 0, buf_len = 2176, timestamp = 0,
  cacheline1 = 0x1da918d80, {userdata = 0x0, udata64 = 0}, pool = 0x1da9a8c00,
  next = 0x0, {tx_offload = 1313294, {l2_len = 14, l3_len = 20, l4_len = 20,
      tso_segsz = 0, outer_l3_len = 0, outer_l2_len = 0}}, priv_size = 72,
  timesync = 0, seqn = 0, shinfo = 0x0, dynfield1 = {0, 0}}
```

note: The same code can be sent correctly if the hinic NIC is used.

Comment: from gdb tx_pkts[0] shows `pkt_len = 1514,   data_len = 54 with nb_segs = 2`. But as per your code snippet `m->data_len = 1514; m->pkt_len = 1514 + 1460 + 1460 ....;`. Something is not matching. As per my current understanding, big buffer data is DMA from DRAM to NIC buffer. Based on the offload flags from dpdk rte_mbuf NIC descriptors allows programming the X710 to split into multiple buffers. So GDB should not be spitting the buffers .

Comment: I means: `struct rte_mbuf *head = m;
for (int i =0; i < head->nb_segs; i++) {   // head->nb_segs = 3
    m->ol_flags = PKT_TX_IPV4 | PKT_TX_TCP_CKSUM | PKT_TX_IP_CKSUM | PKT_TX_TCP_SEG | DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_TSO;  m->data_len = 1514 or 1460;m->pkt_len = 1514 + 1460 + 1460;m->l2_len = 14;m->l3_len = 20;m->l4_len = 20;m = m->next;
}
`, above mbuf split by rte_gso_segment: `nb_segments = 3;gso_segments[i]->nb_segs = 2;gso_segments[0]->pkt_len = 1514;gso_segments[0]->data_len = 54, gso_segments[0]->next->data_len = 1460;gso_segments[0]->ol_flags = 0xd0000000000020
`

Comment: By the way, does testpmd example provide cases for testing the TSO feature? and how it is used?

Comment: testpmd does make use of TSO. But Still I am not clear with your code and gdb output. It does not align as I explained `gdb mbuf has 2 segments with first segment data_len = 54`. can you help me understand the problem. live debug

Comment: gdb mbuf is split by rte_gso_segment, gdb mbuf = gso_segments[0];  first segment data_len is package hdr len(14 + 20 + 20), second segment is data len(1460), because i set gso_ctx->gso_size = 1514;.   This is the result of splitting by the rte_gso_segment function.

Comment: For the reason that the len of the first segment is 54, see the following code: https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/v19.11/lib/librte_gso/gso_common.c#L74

Comment: thanks for your input, but as pointed out in the earlier comments I request again ` can you help me understand the problem. live debug`. My concern is your code snippet share which runs a for loop and sets each mbuf header elements with `  m->pkt_len = 1514 + 1460 + 1460 ....;`. Something is not right. Hence requested for a live debug

Comment: according live debug, before rte_gso_segment,  m1->pkt_len=4434, m2->pkt_len=2920,m3->pkt_len=1460.It's my mistake.

Comment: thanks for the update, please note we did not have licve debug yet. But happy to see that you were able to identify the correct size. Now what is issue you are facing?

Comment: The live debug data exceeded StackOverflow word limit, so I didn't post it.   My issue is that the i40e NIC cannot send this split packet. The i40e_xmit_pkts returns OK. The data seems to have been transferred to the DMA, but the data is not sent out,

Comment: thanks now your porblem is clear to me using DPDK i40e PMD you are not able to send multisegmented packets. Quick debug question `1) dpdk version, 2) nic firmware 3) how many segments 4) is multi-seg enabled in port configure 5) total packet size and each segment size and 6) what is your MTU`?

Comment: reason for the above request is you are utilizing `Software TSO` and not `Hardware Assisted TSO`. So I am really want to compare dpdk version against nic firmware, mtu, number of segments, and offloads flags used. Please note after segmentation in SW the `olfalgs` should not be set to again segment.

Comment: 1) dpdk 19.11; 2)driver i40e,version: 2.8.20-k,firmware-version: 6.80 0x80003cfb 1.2007.0;  3) after rte_gso_segment, split 3 mbuf, each mbuf nb_seg is 2, mbuf->datalen is 54, mbuf->next->data_len is 1460; 4) not clear, how to check multi-seg enabled? 5) total packet size is 1514(each mbuf), seg1 size is 54, seg2 size is 1460; 6) MTU is 1500

Comment: after rte_gso_segment, ol_flags is 0xd4000000000020. PKT_TX_TCP_SEG has been removed.

Comment: thanks for your updates, for your question `not clear, how to check multi-seg enabled? ` Please check port config parameters in rte_eth_Dev_configure if multi segments are enabled. In case of X710 Nic not more than 8 segments were not supported. with ` PKT_TX_TCP_SEG removed` is tx happening?

Comment: I use rte_eth_tx_queue_info_get() ,and print info.conf.offloads, DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS flag is set.  does this means multi-seg enabled? ;;  segmen number is 2;;  PTK_TX_TCP_SEG is removed by gso: https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/v19.11/lib/librte_gso/rte_gso.c#L67

Comment: segments is 2, first is 54 bytes, second is 1460 bytes.

Comment: `segments is 2, first is 54 bytes, second is 1460 bytes` not clear what is the expectation. you are trying multi-segment that `first mbuf will have eth + IP + tcp` header. The second mbuf `will be payload, based on the parameters submitted with `rte_falgs should be splitting into multiple packets. then output will be `packet 1 - eth + IP + TCP + payload1`, second  `packet2 - eth + IP + TCP + payload2`, third `packet3 - eth + IP + TCP + payload3`. this is what to expect. Again I offer for a live debug google, zoom, skype

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I call rte_eth_tx_prepare before rte_eth_tx_burst, it can send tcp data normally....   The reason is that the rte_net_intel_cksum_flags_prepare function helped me clear the ipv4_hdr->hdr_checksum, tcp_hdr->cksum.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

tcp_hdr->cksum、ipv4_hdr->hdr_checksum value is dirty, this result packets cannot be sent normally.
advise to execute rte_eth_tx_prepare function before execute rte_eth_tx_burst function to check whether the mbuf is correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).